# Java/Groovy: Interface extending generic List interface

Tags: generics, groovy, interface

I have the following code (in Groovy):

```
interface IMyList extends List<ISomething> {};
```

This works:

```
private List<ISomething> list1 = Arrays.asList(new ISomething[1]);
```

This doesn't (exception shown below):

```
private IMyList list2 = Arrays.asList(new ISomething[1]);
```

The error I get is:

Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[null]' with class 'java.util.Arrays$ArrayList' to class 'IMyList' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: IMyList(null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix this using the Groovy annotation **@Delegate** (still don't know how to do this in Java):

1) change interface to class:

```
class MyList implements List<ISomething> {
       @Delegate List<ISomething> things = Arrays.asList(new ISomething[1]);
};
```

2) change instance:

```
MyList list2 = new MyList();
```

3) Why do this?  I want to use polymorphism in some function definitions:

```
class Foo {
   void bar(MyList list) {...}
   void bar(MyOtherList list) {...}
```

This can't be done with straight generic Lists in the method signatures because of type erasure.